# area of the region bounded by the latus recta of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} =1$ and the tangents to the ellipse drawn at their ends.

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, area, tangent-line

I tried making a diagram of this (please don't look at the numerical values as the tool I used did not let me use the general a, b values. )

[image]

---

So the 2 latus recta here are:  BC and FE
and I think what the question asks here is the area of the polygon ABCDEF. Which, is a combination of two trapeziums by symmetry. So I calculated the area of 1 trapezium and multiplied it by 2 and got the final answer:
$**2e(a^2 + b^2)** $

Puttin x=0 in general equation of a tangent through end points of the latus recta, I got the coordinates of A: (0,a) and D: (0,-a)

As the area of trapezium = $\frac{(h)(p+q)}{2}$

taking the trapezium ABCD, I took **h= ae** as the latus rectum is at a distance of ae from the y-axis, ***p=BC= $\frac{2b^2}{a}$ and q=AD= 2a***

So, the area of trapezium ABCD= **$\frac{1}{2}(ae)\left(\frac{2b^2}{a}+2a  \right)$**

Simplifying and then multiplying it by 2 to get the total area of ABCDEF, I finally got:

**$2e(a^2 + b^2)$**

---

But the answer given in my book is:   $\frac{b^4}{a \sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$

Comment: Please try and use mathjax to format your answer!

Comment: @JamesO'dare done?!

Comment: You should explain how you got your answer, to understand where you went wrong.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Alright I tried explaining how I got it... Please Let me know if I have to do anything else!

Comment: Your solution is correct. You can rewrite your solution substituting $e=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ to have an expression depending only on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: But the answer of the book refers to another area, that of the triangle formed by a latus rectum and the tangents at its endpoints.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Makes sense! Thank You!